# Setting R's `source()` options used by ESS

Tags: ess, r, source

I'm trying to figure out what to add to my .emacs settings file to get ESS to include an option and setting when sending highlighted code to R.  Specifically, I want to set
`source(max.deparse.length=10000)` so that it stops truncating the output (which makes it hard to debug).  Can some one please help me.

- Ubuntu-Mate 20.04
- GNU Emacs 26.3(build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.14) of 2020-03-26, modified by Debian
- ESS version 18.10.2

Comment: Do you run R outside of Emacs? If you only use ESS, you could put that line in your .Rprofile file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do use R from the console some times, but I'm not worried about those situations for now.  I have included `library(default)` and `default(source) <- list(max.deparse.length=100000)` in my .Rprofile and that seems to work.  I'm still curious to know how to do this within ESS and/or if there's a way to set the option without having to use the `default` library, but that's just because I'm a curious beast.